# mxGetProperty function in octave

Tags: octave, mex

I'm trying to adopt some C-coded matlab module to octave. mkoctave returns batch of warning, but no errors and generates mex file. However octave cannot load this file and returns an error:

```
error: JustKmodel.m: /home/simulations/exampls/RetinalMap-master/stepFastGlobal.mex:
failed to load: /home/simulations/exampls/RetinalMap-master/stepFastGlobal.mex: undefined symbol: mxGetProperty
```

As far as I can understand there is no such function GetProperty or library isn't available.

I'll appreciate any ideas how to work around this problem

Comment: That seems like a missing function in Octave's mex interface. You should report it on [Octave's bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave)

Comment: chances are your MEX-files deal with `classdef` objects (retrieving class properties from C code). Not sure you'll be able to port it to Octave at this moment...

Comment: @Amro - Thank you! I give up to port it.